# In Service Now Virtual Agent designer, Can we create a variable in 'Script Output' or 'Script Action' component and use it elsewhere in flow?

Tags: javascript, variables, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I have created a flow in service now virtual agent designer. In one step, it interacts with Watson and fetches some data. My requirement is to save this data and use it further in the flow. Is it possible?
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn5L6.jpg)
[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08TBV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible by attaching the property to the vaVars object.
Whatever you fetch in the Watson call, just attach it by creating a property on the vaVars object, and it will become available to subsequent flow actions.

Do it in the Watson call script action that you are using.